# UDK Using Mobile Emulator without huge load times

Tags: unreal-development-kit

My spec are:

- 4Gb RAM
- GTX560 Ti
- Dual Core Intel 2.8 Ghz processor

UDK takes like 15 minutes to start up when mobile features are on. While launching it stays for 99% of the time on the line `Compiling shaders for material MOBEMU Lit/Unlit and all possibilities to render it`.

So how to get away from this?
Why is it taking so long? Thanks in advance!

Comment: in regards to the "thanks anyways" below...have you done a google search on `UDK MOBEMU` yet?

Comment: I've done it and found how to manually disable Mob emulation but If I want to actually use it how am I supposed to do that with those load times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google serach for MOBEMU revealed: http://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/193948-QUESTION-Disabling-MOBEMU-at-Startup

Comment: I've asked why and what is it. That post gave a fix but that's not all. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why and what: shaders have to be compiled for each platform. Compiled shaders are stored in a cache. UDK ships with shaders compiled for most platforms (stored in the UDKGame\Content\RefShaderCache-* files). Apparently, compiled mobile shaders aren't included, so when you turn on mobile emulation you have to compile them yourself.

To save the compiled results, open the editor. After the shaders finish compiling, close the editor. It'll ask you to save a MobileShaders file. Do that, and you should be good to go.

Comment: First proper comment that actually explaned and gave a solution! Appreciate your support on this matter! 
Thank you.

Comment: You're quite welcome. If you could mark my answer as "correct", I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sure! Maybe you know how does the shaders actually change? What's the difference between the mobile platform and PC? (just wondering)

Comment: I'm not sure of all the details, but mobile GPUs are very different from and have far fewer features than PC GPUs. It's a little bit like running C++ code on Windows vs Linux. The code has to be recompiled for the platform you're targeting, and certain features available on one platform may not be available on another.

Comment: I haven't thought about this earlier. Very big thanks! Now everything is clear.